# Strategy for vast number of potential duplicate rows upon INSERT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have approximately 50,000 3rd party data feeds that will be read every five minutes. The idea is to check for updated content. I have the following tables:

**feeds**

- id
- name
- url

**posts**

- id
- feed_id
- title
- content
- url
- unique_hash (based on url + title)

My first approach was to make posts.unique_hash a unique index field so that upon attempted INSERT I get a failure. The majority of the INSERTs would simply fail (as intended). However, my problem is that I will be needing to run SELECT on the 'posts' table very often (for another part of this application) so having a ton of INSERTS running constantly (with many failing) will consume the resources of the table.

I could of course do a SELECT on the 'posts' table before attempting to INSERT but that would be even more resource intensive.

I am looking for the best approach which will keep the resources of my 'posts' table free for making many SELECT queries. Use an index table? Use a caching mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

A (unique) key can be multiple fields, so you wouldn't need to compute a hash.  You can make a unique key be the combination of the feed_id, title, and url which would prevent duplicate info from being inserted.

There isn't much you can do aside from dedicating more resources to how much of your indexes are cached, etc... since simply doing an INSERT would be the fewest queries to the server.  Using the unique index would just have bad inserts fail and eliminate you doing a select or something to see if it should even insert.

How you do your SELECTs from posts can differ quite a bit - you'd have to tell us what you'd want to pull back (`select * from posts where feed_id = ?` or something else, etc...).  Depending how you query it for info will determine how functional additional indexes may be on that table.